# How can I tell if a set is compact and connected?

Tags: compactness, connectedness

For expample if I consider the subspace $A_n$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by
$$A_n=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y=|x|^{2n+1}\}$$
and
$$X=\bigcup_{n\ge0} A_n$$
Using Heine-Borel I just have to prove it's closed and it's limited, for the first consideration, but how should I do that?

Comment: Neither $A_n$ seems to be bounded.

Comment: Since you are working in 2-D, you have the luxury of visualization. Start experimenting: sketch $A_0$, then sketch $A_1$, then $A_{2}$, etc..  See how they look and determine how $X$ will look.  Mathematics is as experimental as physics is: all the solutions are sought intuitively, and only once found are confirmed formally (if the researchers were able to confirm them at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set is not bounded so I don't think that it will be possible to show that it is bounded.

If you draw a picture of the set you will see that there are infinitely many distinct unbounded curves originating at the origin.

It may also be possible to imagine a small ball at the origin and very thin open sets surrounding each distinct curve emitting from the origin, these open sets being thin enough to not overlap the other curves coming out of the origin (as long as you are away from the origin to begin with which that original ball around the origin lets you do).  These thin open sets along with that ball will provide an open cover of the set which is infinite and has no subcover at all, since leaving out one of the thin open sets will leave out the curve that goes along with it.